# location.reload doesn't reload the page when I'm using it in keyDown event handler when ESC is pressed. Only in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I find out that location.reload() call doesn't do anything when I called to it from keyDown event handler when ESC button is pressed. Does anybody knows some workaround how to reload the page? Also I find http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4922 and it looks like this problem is already fixed.
Here is a sample of code.
subscription to event:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        closeVideoPopup();
    }
});
```

And closeVideoPopup() method:

```
function closeVideoPopup() {
jQuery('#fade, .window_container').fadeOut(function(){
        jQuery('#fade, a.close').remove();
    });

jQuery('ul.tabs').css('z-index', '99');
jQuery('div.framing_slider').css('z-index', '9999');

location.reload();

return false;
```

}

**Please note this code works perfect in all browsers except FF**.

Comment: Which 'all browsers' did you test in?

Comment: And which version of jQuery are you using? If the issue is fixed but you're using a version of jQuery that's older than the one that has the fix, this issue is expected...

Comment: Chrome and IE, I'm using the latest version of jQuery (1.8.2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key stops the refresh immediately after you fire it in Firefox.

Use a `setTimeout` so the `location.reload()` will execute after the event has already finished bubbling.

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        setTimeout(closeVideoPopup, 0);
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TKmS5/5/)

---

Or better, just call [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) so the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key won't cancel the page reload:

```
jQuery(document).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        event.preventDefault();
        closeVideoPopup();
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TKmS5/6/)

Comment: Thanks for your attention but this doesn't help. Behaviour is staying the same. I also try to increase time out value.

Comment: Both of these work just fine on my Firefox 16 and Firefox Nightly 19. Check out your Firebug/error console to see if there isn't anything else breaking your code.

Comment: As for my case I found out the work around, and your second post helps me. So the work around for me is:
jQuery(document).keydown(function (event) {
     if (event.keyCode == 27) {
         closeVideoPopup();
         event.preventDefault();
         location.reload();
     }
 });

Obviously I have removed this string:

    location.reload();
from closeVideoPopup() method.