# Form not submited on keydown event when event is triggered by 'ESC' key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to submit form on hitting the 'ESC' key. I have the folowing code to do so:

```
<form id="testForm" name="testForm" method="post" action=""  >
   <input name="givenAnswer" id="realInput"  value="" type="text" onclick="doSubmit()" autofocus>
</form>

<script>
   document.getElementById('realInput').onkeydown = function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 27){
           event.preventDefault();
           document.testForm.submit();
        }
   };
</script>
```

but this does not work correctly (I try it with FF 47.0.1): 
if I type a text to input field, and hit ESC key, form is not submited. The form is submited on ESC key only in the case I click the input filed by mouse right before I hit ESC key (and this is valid only if line 'event.preventDefault();' is excluded from the script). But this is not expected behavoir.

The same is with this script:

```
<script>
    var el = document.getElementById("realInput");
    el.onkeydown = function(event) {
       if (event.keyCode == 27) {
           document.testForm.submit();
       }
    };
</script>
```

Would anybody know to tell me what is the problem and suggest solution please?

I foud also these links with similar issue, but the solution proposed there didn't work for me:

[location.reload doesn't reload the page when I'm using it in keyDown event handler when ESC is pressed. Only in FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306492/location-reload-doesnt-reload-the-page-when-im-using-it-in-keydown-event-handl)

https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4922

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `e.keyCode == 27`, try `e.which == 27`.

Comment: No, this is no the case! The command 'document.testForm.submit();' is reached, problem is it takes no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first snippet, Just change `event` to `e` in `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Thanks a lot for correction. After trying hundreeds of changes and modifications during the whole day, I wasn't able to apply correctly this last one.